# Javascript Regex Issue - UserName

Tags: javascript, regex

problem Statement.

The User Name should be between 6 and 32 alphanumeric characters. Space is allowed, unless it is the first or last character. Do not put together more than two of the same characters. Allowed the following special characters: @ # $. The user name is case-sensitive

Current Regex we have is

```
(?!.*(.)\1{2})^[^\s]([0-9]*)([A-Za-z]+)(\w|\@|\#|\$|\s|\-)*[^\s]
```

worked fine for these test cases

```
eldricdsouza
eldric1dsouza
eldric@dsouza
eldric#dsouza
eldric$dsouza
eldric dsouza
 eldric 
 eldricdsouza1
!eldric123#
eeeldric123#
eellldric123#
!user1405!
user@1405!
user@1405#$
user@1405###
user@1405###$
user@144405##$
user@14405##$
```

Did not work well for these...

```
5634user@14405##$ ---gave an error...when this is valid.
usereldric_   --- underscore is not valid
usereldric-dsouza  --- hyphen is not valid.
5634user@14405##$ ---gave an error...when this is valid.
usereldric_   --- underscore is not valid
usereldric-dsouza  --- hyphen is not valid.
```

or this ...

```
UseerrNaame78
```

Comment: So, what's the problem with your current regex?

Comment: What @FrédéricHamidi is asking is what string you expect to match which is not matching or the other way around?

Comment: does "more than two of the same characters" mean "more than two of the same characters back to back" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A regex that meets your requirements is this one:

```
/^([a-zA-Z@#$])(?!\1)(?:([a-zA-Z@#$ ])(?!\2)){4,30}[a-zA-Z@#$]$/
```

DEMO: http://regex101.com/r/dS9kE2

Some explanations:

- `(?!\1)` - (or 2) looks ahead that the next character is different than the last one matched
- `[a-zA-Z@#$]` - class of approved characters for first and last positions
- `[a-zA-Z@#$ ]` - class of approved characters in the middle
- `{4,30}` middle portion must have between (6-2) and (32-2) characters

Answer (score 1):

You can use this pattern to not have more than 2 same characters in all the string:

```
^(?=[a-zA-Z])(?:([\w@#$-]| (?!$))(?!.*\1.*\1)){6,32}$
```

But to not have more than 2 same characters back to back, you can use:

```
^(?=[a-zA-Z])(?:([\w@#$-]| (?!$))(?!\1\1)){6,32}$
```

Comment: This will allow space at last character.

Comment: @M42: Thanks, I have forgotten this!

Comment: many thanks everyone who took the time to look at the regex -- derived the final expression from your expression. It satisfies all the test cases....  
Final Expression  

(?!.*[\!|\_]\1{0})^(?=[a-zA-Z0-9])(?:([\w@#$]| (?!$))(?!\1\1)){6,32}$